# How to create a Confetti effect using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

I want to create a confetti effect (screen shot attached) where the flakes should be TRIANGULAR shape(currently they are RECTANGULAR) . I am using the following javascript code to get the effect. However, i want the flakes to start falling from top to bottom when a webpage got opened. Right now the moment we open the page the page is flooded by the flakes. I was looking, how i can blank the screen and make the flakes come down slowly. Can anyone please help me to sort out this effect:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var W = window.innerWidth;
  var H = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = W;
  canvas.height = H;

  var mp = 1000; //max particles
  var particles = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
    particles.push({
      x: Math.random() * W, //x-coordinate
      y: Math.random() * H, //y-coordinate
      r: Math.random() * 18 + 1, //radius
      d: Math.random() * mp, //density
      color: "rgba(" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255)) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255)) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255)) + ", 0.8)",
      tilt: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 5
    });
  }

  //Lets draw the flakes
  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
      var p = particles[i];
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = p.r;
      ctx.strokeStyle = p.color; // Green path
      ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
      ctx.lineTo(p.x + p.tilt + p.r / 2, p.y + p.tilt);
      ctx.stroke(); // Draw it
    }

    update();
  }

  var angle = 0;

  function update() {
    angle += 0.01;
    for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
      var p = particles[i];
      p.y += Math.cos(angle + p.d) + 1 + p.r / 2;
      p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;
      if (p.x > W + 5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H) {
        if (i % 3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
        {
          particles[i] = {
            x: Math.random() * W,
            y: -10,
            r: p.r,
            d: p.d,
            color: p.color,
            tilt: p.tilt
          };
        }
      }
    }
  }
  setInterval(draw, 20);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Fiddle [JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mzack5020/72dun3fx/)

End Goal: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gktl.png)

Comment: can you make it a working snippet ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzack5020/72dun3fx/). It's acting as described, top down effect. What's the problem?

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for that. There are two things i need to change : 1. The shape of the flakes from rectangular to triangular. 2. As the screen is loaded with the flakes when the page loads so i want the flakes to come down slowly from the top of the page. Thanks

Comment: @MatthewZackschewski can you please suggest ?

Comment: I'm trying to get a working fiddle now but I'm just using this [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes) to try to change you draw() function to do a fill instead of a stroke. Not yet successful

Answer (score 1):

To make a triangle, you'll want to draw a shape, rather than drawing a thick line.

```
// Rectangle
ctx.strokeStyle = p.color;
ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
ctx.lineTo(p.x + p.tilt + p.r / 2, p.y + p.tilt);
ctx.stroke();

// Triangle
ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
ctx.lineTo(p.x + 10, p.y);
ctx.lineTo(p.x + 5, p.y + 10);
ctx.fill();
```

The following code is updated to do both the things you want:

- The rectangles are changed to triangles
- The page starts with 5 triangles, and then uses `setTimeout` to add a snowflake every tenth of a second. (The loop can also be removed to start with 0 snowflakes, or snowflakes can be added faster/slower by changing the timeout.)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/72dun3fx/13/

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var W = window.innerWidth;
  var H = window.innerHeight;
  var particles = [];
  var angle = 0;
  canvas.width = W;
  canvas.height = H;

  // Add starting particles
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    addParticle();
  }
  // Add a particle every tenth of a second
  setInterval(addParticle, 100);
  // Update the particles so they fall
  setInterval(draw, 20);

  // Add a single particle
  function addParticle() {
    if (particles.length > 1000) {
      return false;
    }

    particles.push({
      x: Math.random() * W, //x-coordinate
      y: Math.random() * H, //y-coordinate
      r: Math.random() * 18 + 1, //radius
      d: Math.random() * particles.length, //density
      color: "rgba(" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255)) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255)) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255)) + ", 0.8)",
      tilt: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 5
    });
  }

  /* Draw the particles */
  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      var p = particles[i];
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = p.r;
      ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
      ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
      ctx.lineTo(p.x + 10, p.y);
      ctx.lineTo(p.x + 5, p.y + 10);
      ctx.fill();
    }

    update();
  }

  function update() {
    angle += 0.01;
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      var p = particles[i];
      p.y += Math.cos(angle + p.d) + 1 + p.r / 2;
      p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;
      if (p.x > W + 5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H) {
        if (i % 3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
        {
          particles[i] = {
            x: Math.random() * W,
            y: -10,
            r: p.r,
            d: p.d,
            color: p.color,
            tilt: p.tilt
          };
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Alison, it solves half of the problem. My end goal is something like the screen shot (attached to the post
) . Any additional suggestions from your experience?

Answer (score 1):

I made a slight edit to the answer above to tweek it more towards your specifications. Edited the Y component so triangles cannot go past the middle of the canvas. Secondly, made the triangles begin at the top of the canvas. Hopefully this helps.

**EDIT : Is this what you were looking for?**
Side Note : I added a Math.random() * 7 in the draw() function because I think the effect is cool but if you don't like it, replace it with a 10 (that was what it was set to before.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var W = window.innerWidth;
var H = window.innerHeight - 30;
canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H;

var particles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  addParticle();
}
setInterval(addParticle(), 10);

/* Add a single particle */
function addParticle() {
  if (particles.length > 1000) {
    return false;
  }

  particles.push({
    x: Math.random() * W, //x-coordinate
    y: H, //y-coordinate
    r: Math.random() * 18 + 1, //radius
    d: Math.random() * particles.length, //density
    color: "rgba(" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255)) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255)) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255)) + ", 0.8)",
    tilt: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 5
  });
}

/* Draw the particles */
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    var p = particles[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = p.r;
    ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
    ctx.lineTo(p.x + 10, p.y);
    ctx.lineTo(p.x + 5, p.y + (Math.random() * 7));
    ctx.fill();
  }

  update();
}

var angle = 0.02;

function update() {
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    var p = particles[i];
    p.y += Math.cos(angle) + 1 + p.r / 10;
    p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;
    if (p.x > W + 5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H) {
      if (i % 3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
      {
        particles[i] = {
          x: Math.random() * W,
          y: -10,
          r: p.r,
          d: p.d,
          color: p.color,
          tilt: p.tilt
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
setInterval(draw, 20);
```

```css
canvas {
  z-index: 999;
}

.thankYouBanner {
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  bottom:20%;
  left:50%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.thankYouBanner h2 {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  left: -50%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div class="thankYouBanner">
  <h2>
    Thank You, John Doh
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Matthew. I have attached a screen shot with my question. I am trying to get that result. Can you please share the solution as per your experience. Thanks

Comment: Edited answer. Lmk if that is what you're looking for

Comment: @Victor if the answer above is sufficient, please mark it as the right answer. Thanks!